# How to extract certain data using Regex?

Tags: regex, elixir

I have some data after a GET request and what I am trying to do is extract from the structure of the data that looks like [this](https://hastebin.com/femamuxato.xml) what is between `<a href=...> this </a>`.

In the example posted there, for example, I would like to have

```
set_status(status, game)
```

and

```
set_status(pid, status, game)
```

How would the regex look like for that?

Keep in mind that the functions may or may not have parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```rb
with text <-
  Enum.join(["<a href=...> this </a>", "<a href=...> that </a>"]),
do: Regex.scan(~r|<a.+?>(.*?)</a>|, text) |> Enum.map(fn [_, text] -> text end)
#⇒ [" this ", " that "]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this regex out

> \d+" *>([^<>]+)